# How to translate simple "if/else" with OR to pseudocode to MIPS?

Tags: assembly, mips, pseudocode

I am trying to understand the principle of pseudocode to MIPS.
It surely is very simple but I just can't understand how do I represent the "OR" in the following:

```
IF  (b<1) OR (b>3) THEN
b:=b-1;
ELSE 
b:= a+1;
END;
```

Comment: Hint: Get rid of the OR, and implement it with only two IF statements and GOTOs.

Comment: What? No. That is a high-level language construct that does not exist in assembly. Show what you've tried.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/15375267/583570

Comment: What Jonathan Reinhart is trying to say is, a (naive) compiler for a high level language (such as your pseudocode) would first break the IF statement apart into two IFs with simpler conditions. You must do the same, manually.