# Nested For Loop Multiple Conditions Mips

Tags: c, mips

I have a nested for loop with multiple conditions to convert using MIPS. My specific question is how would I break down this line from the C code in order to complete that instruction in 1 branch statement in the MIPS conversion?  --> **`if((a[i] > 0) && (b[j] > 0))`**

*I've made an update to the code to break down the if condition. I am getting an error when running on Mars. The error is:

**line 28: Runtime exception at 0x00400074: fetch address not aligned on word boundary 0x10010069**

The C code is here:

```
    int i, j, M, N, count;
    int a[];
    int b[];

    for(i=0; i<M; i++) {
    for(j=0; j<N; j++) {
        if((a[i] > 0) && (b[j] > 0)) {
            count = count + 1;
        }
      }
    }
```

What I have is here:

```
.data
a: .space 100   # Declare a array with 100 bytes of data 
b: .space 100   # Declare b array with 100 bytes of data
i: .word 0  # Declare i counter
j: .word    # Declare j counter

.text

addi $t0, $zero, 10 # $t0 variable with score 10
addi $s1, $zero, 0 # $s1 variable with array index 0
sw $t0, a($s1) # Store 10 into a array at location 

addi $t1, $zero, 15 # $t0 variable with score 15
addi $s2, $zero, 0 # $s2 variable with array index 0
sw $t1, b($s2) # Store 15 into b array at location 0

lw $t2, i($zero) # Initialize loop index i to 0
lw $t3, j($zero) # Intialize loop index j to 0
addi $s2, $zero, 5 # Initialize M to 5
addi $s3, $zero, 5 # Initialize N to 5
addi $s4, $zero, 0 # Initialize count to 0

OuterLoop:  beq $t2, $s2, Exit # i=M Exit the loop
    lw $t0, a($s1) # Load value from a array
    bgt $t0, 0, InnerLoop # if a[i] > 0

InnerLoop:  beq $t3, $s3, Exit # j=N Exit the loop
    lw $t1, b($s2) # Load value from b array
    bgt $t1, 0, Increment # if b[j] > 0

Increment:  addi $s4, $s4, 1 # Increment count by 1
    addi $t2, $t2, 1 # Increment i by 1
    addi $t3, $t3, 1 # Increment j by 1
    j OuterLoop     

Exit:
```

Comment: You realize you can hoist the `a[i] > 0` out of the inner loop?

Comment: @EOF what do you mean?

Comment: You could rewrite the loops as `for (i = 0, i < M; i++) if (a[i] > 0) for (j = 0; i < N; j++) count += b[j] > 0;`

Comment: @EOF thanks. I've made the changes. I am getting an error when I run the code on Mars though. The error occurs on the second lw statement in the inner loop

Comment: @Kay Include the precise error in your question please.

Comment: @Magisch thanks. I've included the error in the question.

Comment: Try using `.align 2` before `a: .space 100` to have the buffer correctly word-aligned.

Comment: You seem using wrong register for the offset of memory loading. Loop counter with proper offset calculation should be used instead of registers having how many loop will occur.

Comment: Jumping to just after the branch instruction seems meaningless.

Comment: @MikeCAT hi, I'm not following. Where exactly would that code you posted go within the code I wrote?

Comment: @Kay I updated my answer.

Comment: @MikeCAT thank you. I'll test it in MARS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `if((a[i] > 0) && (b[j] > 0))` cannot be done in one branch because the second operand of `&&` must not be evaluated when the first operand is true (non-zero).

This is an example of MIPS code standing for `if((a[i] > 0) & (b[j] > 0)) count = count + 1;` (not tested)

```
    # assuming that i = $t2, j = $t3, count = $s4
    sll $t4, $t2, 2 # calculate offset of a[i]
    lw $t5, a($t4) # load a[i]
    sll $t4, $t3, 2 # calculate offset of b[j]
    lw $t6, b($t4) # load b[j]
    slt $t4, $zero, $t5 # $t4 = (a[i] > 0)
    slt $t7, $zero, $t6 # $t7 = (b[j] > 0)
    and $t4, $t4, $t7 # $t4 = (a[i] > 0) & (b[j] > 0)
    beq $t4, $zero, NotTrue # skip increment if the condition is false
    sll $zero, $zero, 0 # nop: prevent increment from being executed when the condition is false
    addi $s4, $s4, 1 # count = count + 1
NotTrue:
```

**UPDATE:** With correction of other mistakes, your code should be like this:

```
.data
a: .space 100   # Declare a array with 100 bytes of data 
bb: .space 100   # Declare b array with 100 bytes of data

.text
main:
    addi $t0, $zero, 10 # $t0 variable with score 10
    addi $s1, $zero, 0 # $s1 variable with array index 0
    sw $t0, a($s1) # Store 10 into a array at location 

    addi $t1, $zero, 15 # $t0 variable with score 15
    addi $s2, $zero, 0 # $s2 variable with array index 0
    sw $t1, bb($s2) # Store 15 into bb array at location 0

    addi $t2, $zero, 0 # Initialize loop index i to 0

    addi $s2, $zero, 5 # Initialize M to 5
    addi $s3, $zero, 5 # Initialize N to 5
    addi $s4, $zero, 0 # Initialize count to 0

OuterLoop:  beq $t2, $s2, Exit # i=M Exit the loop

    addi $t3, $zero, 0 # Intialize loop index j to 0
InnerLoop:  beq $t3, $s3, ExitInnerLoop # j=N Exit the loop

    sll $t4, $t2, 2 # calculate offset of a[i]
    lw $t5, a($t4) # load a[i]
    sll $t4, $t3, 2 # calculate offset of b[j]
    lw $t6, bb($t4) # load b[j]
    slt $t4, $zero, $t5 # $t4 = (a[i] > 0)
    slt $t7, $zero, $t6 # $t7 = (b[j] > 0)
    and $t4, $t4, $t7 # $t4 = (a[i] > 0) & (b[j] > 0)
    beq $t4, $zero, NoIncrement # skip increment if the condition is false
    nop # prevent increment from being executed when the condition is false
    addi $s4, $s4, 1 # Increment count by 1
NoIncrement:

    addi $t3, $t3, 1 # Increment j by 1
    j InnerLoop
    nop
ExitInnerLoop:
    addi $t2, $t2, 1 # Increment i by 1
    j OuterLoop
    nop

Exit:
    # exit program
    addi $v0, $zero, 10
    syscall
```

I changed the label `b` to `bb` because my QtSpim complained about it for using opcode as label.