# How to write an if statement with and in assembly language x86

Tags: if-statement, assembly, x86

How do I write a code in x86 assembly where there is an and in the if statement. For example, how do I write this code in assembly:

if(x>5) && (y>6){
}

What about or?

if(x>5) || (y>6){
}

Is there a special line of code for And and Or?

Comment: Assembly language does not have an "if statement". You will have to make one yourself

Comment: The approach is to decompose using logical transformations.  The best approach to logical transformations is to first translate that to if-goto-label form, because that helps make it easier to decompose.  That transformation to if-goto-label requires an inversion/negation.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74496686/how-to-write-multiple-condition-if-else-statement-mips/74496777#74496777).

Comment: When starting with && as in `if ...&&... { }`, with negation as needed for if-goto-label, `if ...&&... { }` becomes `if ...||... goto ...`.  We can then split both halves of the `if ...||... goto` into two separate `if ... goto ...` statements.

Comment: When starting with || as in `if ...||... { }`, again we need to negate for if-goto-label so that effectively becomes `if ...&&... goto ...`.  We can similarly split both halves of the `if ...&&... goto` into two by adjusting appropriate label targets and also negating conditions.